# Firebase credentials don't work when authenticated

Tags: javascript, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to implement an authentication for firebase in my react app. I do that with github but it's not relevant.

So I have some credentials and they work just fine. I can fetch my data from db and manilpulate it.

Until I login...

After successfully executing this: `firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(githubProvider).then ...`

I start constantly receiving warnings of that kind:

`FIREBASE WARNING: Provided authentication credentials for the app named "[DEFAULT]" are invalid. This usually indicates your app was not initialized correctly. Make sure the "apiKey" and "databaseURL" properties provided to initializeApp() match the values provided for your app at https://console.firebase.google.com/.`

I can't do anything to my DB.

And this continues until I log out with `firebase.auth().signOut().then ...` then everything works fine again.

inb4: I am 100% confident that my credentials are correct. I have copied and pasted them several times.

Can someone give me insight on what is going on in that case?

And here's how I initialize the App

```
import firebase from 'firebase';

try {
    const config = {
        apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
        authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
        databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
        projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
        storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
        messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    };

    firebase.initializeApp(config);
} catch (e) {}

export const githubProvider = new firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider();
export const firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref();
export default firebase;
```

Comment: Can you include your code where you are calling `initializeApp`? Leaving out the actual credentials of course.

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: Were you using version 4.1.4? There was a critical bug in that. It was fixed in 4.1.5: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#4.1.5

Comment: Omg no way! It really was 4.1.4. Upgrading solved the problem! But didn't bring all these hours of debugging back.